# Dependency Injection how to inject only part of arguments?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

Is it possible to inject only part of constructor arguments? I would like to achieve something like this:

```
@Injectable()
class A {
    constructor(param1: string, private param2?: SomeType){}
}


class B extends A {
    constructor(){
          super("some string value");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `@Optional()` decorator makes it optional:

```
@Injectable()
class A {
    constructor(@Optional() param1: string, private param2?: SomeType){}
}
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Optional-decorator.html

The `?` after `param2` indicates that you want this parameter to be optional, but you can't have a mandatory parameter of a primitive type (`Object`, `string`, `number`, `boolean`) for injectables.

You can use a string key for a provider using `@Inject(...)` though, like:

```
@Injectable()
class A {
    constructor(@Inject('someName')param1: string, @Optional() private param2?: SomeType){}
}
```

and

```
providers: [{provide: 'someName', useValue: 'some string value'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that you did not got my point exactly. What I want to achieve is to pass primitive in super() and let rest of parameters to be injected by DI. I want to achieve that, because my Class A is extended by multiple classes in my project, and param1 is changed for every new instance of that class, while rest of fields are shared by the derived classes - ie http service (that's why I want to use DI for them).

Comment: When I changed my code according to your answer, I still doesn't get last parameter initialized (it is undefined).

Comment: You are right, I missed a part of your question. You need to repeat all constructor parameters of the super class in the subclass if you want them to be injected (if the subclass has a constructor).

Comment: Yeah.. And that is my point. I did not want to have something like:   constructor(http2: Http, anotherServie: SomeService) { super(param1, param2, htt2p, anotherService)}    - http2 because of name collision between base and derived classes. I don't like to have extra params in derived class constructor, only to pass them up... I was looking for something like @Autowired in Spring for Java

Comment: Sadly, not wanting it is not enough. That's how constructors work in TS (and many other languages).

Comment: So there is no way to inject just part of arguments? Or maybe different way. Can I use @Inject() in other method then constructor? It would be also ok, I can use less parameters in constructor and call internal function 'initializeServices()' which would inject objects.

Comment: My answer shows how to inject part of the arguments (`@Optional()`) but arguments that are only in the super class constructor but not in the subclass constructor are not considered at all by DI.

Comment: You can use `constructor(injector:Injector, ...) { this.foo = injector.get(Foo); }` but I'd discourage using it. It makes code harder to understand.

Comment: Ok. The problem itself, is not injecting part of arguments, but DI mechanism itself. I have make some tests, and what I found is that if I will call constructor by super() instantiated are only values provided by derived class (dependency injection is omitted). If I won't call super (dependency injection works).

Comment: So I see only two possible solutions: 1. pass derived-class-specific params as injected values. or: 2. use another method to initialize fields needed for given class instance.